# what is PLVtab.rowintab in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to know what is `PLVtab.rowintab`?

Because one of my procedures having this code:

```
IF PLVtab.rowintab (from_status_tbl, other_sup_rec.dcc_status) IS NOT NULL
           THEN
```

Please let me know if you know this.

Comment: It looks like PLVTAB is a package and rowintab is a procedure or function.

Comment: I guess procedure is not yours. Does google not work ?

Comment: Without looking at the source code (control-rightclick in PL/SQL Developer, but I don't know what tools you have), I would guess it checks whether `other_sup_rec.dcc_status` occurs within `from_status_tbl`.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly somebody in your organization has been reading Steven Feuerstein's books on PL/SQL programming.

The `PLVtab` package is one of a suite of helper packages Steven wrote and published back in the 1990s. (The suite was called PL/Vision, hence the prefix).  `PLVtab` has [some utility methods for working with PL/SQL tables](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/advanced-oracle-plsql/1565922387/1565922387_plsql-adv-ch-8.html), what we now call collections to avoid confusion.

However it looks like `rowintab` is not a function in the original package, so it must be an in-house extension.

Steven was an early evangelist of PL/SQL as a proper programming language, and his books are worth a read. [Find out more about "Advanced Oracle PL/SQL Programming with Packages"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922389.do)

---

> "Can you please tell me the logic or concept behind that code"

Alas no. It's not a standard Oracle package. What you can do is look at the source code. In an ideal world all your PL/SQL, including third party libraries, would be under source control. So check your SVN Repository (or whatever you use).

But if you're not living in that ideal world you can find it in your database.

This will tell you the owning schema:

```
select owner
from all_objects
where object_name = 'PLVTAB'
and object_type = 'PACKAGE';
```

Because it's a package you will need to connect as that user to see the source code (`execute` privilege doesn't allow us to see package bodies). If you can't connect to the user you will need to ask your friendly DBA for assistance.

```
select text
from user_source
where name = 'PLVTAB'
and type = 'PACKAGE'
order by line;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the logic or concept behind that code. I mean PLVtab.rowintab is having some logic. Could you please help me to understand the concept for that??